# Get selected dropdownlist value inside a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist inside of a repeater control that I'm trying to get the value of and I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I am not sure what else to try.  Thanks

**ASPX CODE:**

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="GeneralRepeater" runat="server" 
             OnItemDataBound="GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound" 
                onitemcommand="GeneralRepeater_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
             <td class="style2">
             </td>
              <td class="style2">
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="GeneralDDL"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"  DataTextField="DiagnosisCode" 
                  DataValueField="DiagnosisCode" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
               </td>

            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void GeneralRepeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender,
                                               RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("GeneralDDL");
            Diagnosis oDiagnosis = new Diagnosis();
            DataView dv = new DataView(oDiagnosis.GetDiagnosis());
            myDDL.DataSource = dv;
            myDDL.DataTextField = "DiagnosisCode";
            myDDL.DataValueField = "DiagnosisCode";
            myDDL.DataBind();

        }
    }

protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ProductSelected;
    string FeatureSelected;
    string SectionSelected;


    foreach(RepeaterItem dataItem in GeneralRepeater.Items)
    {
         ProductSelected = ((DropDownList)GeneralRepeater.FindControl("GeneralDDL")).SelectedItem.Text; //error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    }                   
}
```

I having problem on Saving the selected value..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What i find in the code is you are looping through the generalrepeater items. You are accessing the repeater item as dataItem.  I tried out this code out here and ideally your code should say

```
foreach(RepeaterItem dataItem in GeneralRepeater.Items)        
{               
  ProductSelected = ((DropDownList)dataItem.FindControl("GeneralDDL")).SelectedItem.Text; //No error
}
```

instead of

```
foreach(RepeaterItem dataItem in GeneralRepeater.Items) 
{
   ProductSelected = ((DropDownList)GeneralRepeater.FindControl("GeneralDDL")).SelectedItem.Text; //error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think ecoGreen is right. Though "dataItem" might be a bit of a misnomer.